# iPhone - properties, ivars, etc

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-blocks

On [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22), the author has these declarations:

on .h

```
UIViewController *presentingViewController;
...

@property (retain) UIViewController *presentingViewController;
```

on .m

```
@synthesize presentingViewController;
```

at some point in code, **inside a block**, he does:

```
self.presentingViewController = viewController;
```

and then

```
[presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

I find this very strange. If is is assigning the viewController to self.presentingViewController, should't it be calling

```
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

?

I have changed his code to

.h

```
@property (retain) UIViewController *presentingViewController;
```

.m

```
@synthesize presentingViewController = _presentingViewController;
```

and what I do is:

```
self.presentingViewController = viewController;
```

and then

```
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

the problem is that, self.presentingViewController is nil at this line, even being declared as retain and never being released.

any clues?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remove the instance variable `UIViewController *presentingViewController` when you added the instance variable `UIViewController *_presentingViewController` ? If not i would put money on you accidentally using the wrong one at some point.

Stepping through.. originally you had an instance variable

```
UIViewController *presentingViewController;
```

And from the property syntactic sugar you have the two accessor methods for setting and getting the variable

```
- (UIViewController *)presentingViewController;
- (void)setPresentingViewController:(UIViewController *)val;
```

at some point in code, inside a block, he does:

```
[self setPresentingViewController: viewController]; // uses setter
```

and then

```
[presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; // uses instance variable
```

which is fine, but you think it should be

```
UIViewController *localPresentingViewController = [self presentingViewController]; // uses getter
[localPresentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

which is also fine but somewhat unnecessary.

Then you added a new instance variable:-

```
@synthesize presentingViewController = _presentingViewController;
```

so now you have

```
UIViewController *presentingViewController;
UIViewController *_presentingViewController;

// These now get / set _presentingViewController
- (UIViewController *)presentingViewController;
- (void)setPresentingViewController:(UIViewController *)val;
```

But almost certainly, somewhere you are confusing the two ivars (or you aren't aware you have two ivars) presentingViewController / _presentingViewController and still have a reference to the presentingViewController ivar, leading you to think your property is nil.

Comment: Hi, I am not declaring the ivar at all, I am just synthesizing it using @synthesize presentingViewController = _presentingViewController; that I suppose will create the underscore ivar anyway. Now it is working fine. The code in that tutorial has a lot of small issues like that, and I am having a huge time fixing them all. Anyway, +1 for your answer.

Comment: When you say 'i suppose will create the underscore ivar anyway' - it sounds like you don't realise that that is all synthesize does. It creates the var, the getter method and the setter method at compile time, it's just to save you typing. If either the var, the getter or the setter already exist (because you typed it) it won't add it again. synthesize foo; creates an ivar called foo, the -(id)foo; method and the -(void)setFoo:(id)arg; method. Using the options on @synthesize you can use custom names for any of these, but you should use the defaults unless you have a good reason.

Comment: properties are only syntactical sugar for legacy objective-c. In modern objective-c (the kind we build today's iOS apps with), declaring an identically named ivar in conduction with a property is unnecessary, and confusing (as the OP demonstrates). See "Runtime Differences" in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

Comment: @claireware - I deliberately tried to avoid saying anything that contradicts this. If i have i apologise, feel free to edit my answer. I disagree with your opinion that the OP's confusion demonstrates that declaring an identically named ivar and property is confusing. I read the question as the OP wanted a property backed by a differently named iVar. In my opinion not explicitly declaring the iVar that backs the property only adds to the confusion (but i was careful not to say this). in the method declaration '-(int)foo' the return type is unnessesary but that doesn't make it bad, bad style.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it should be:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

However, reinstate this:

```
@synthesize presentingViewController;
```

And remove the instance decoration of a similar looking variable:

```
UIViewController *presentingViewController;
```

Comment: @hooleyhoop - yes there is, they create both an instance variable presentingViewController and a property presentingViewController. They assign the created view controller to the property version, but then use the instance version to display/dismiss a model view controller. Since the instance variable was never linked to the property, this will not work. Furthermore, it's just bad, bad style to have an instance variable and property identically named. There is no need for the instance variable, hence my advice to the OP to remove it and only use the property version of the variable.